# MSB3021 walking through the ASP.net Core Razor Pages Tutorial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to do the Microsoft "Razor Pages Movies" tutorial to give myself a basic grounding on ASP.net Core Razor pages. I get to this step here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

I followed the steps to the letter just to make sure I didn't do anything wrong. I've created two separate projects. It's on my dev machine, so permissions are fine; just to be paranoid, I gave Everyone Full Control on the folder and all objects within it. But I keep getting this error when I try to build the app using -:

```
Build started at 12:13 PM...
1>------ Build started: Project: RazorPagesMovie, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5198,5): error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "D:\ASP.net Core Tutorial Razor Pages\RazorPagesMovie\RazorPagesMovie\obj\Debug\net8.0\apphost.exe" to "bin\Debug\net8.0\RazorPagesMovie.exe". Access to the path 'bin\Debug\net8.0\RazorPagesMovie.exe' is denied.
1>Done building project "RazorPagesMovie.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 12:13 PM and took 00.427 seconds ==========
```

I'm not sure where/how to debug this particular error, and I find it weird that it's happening when I'm doing the "Hello world" tutorial. Where should I be looking in terms of this error and how to debug/solve it? Thanks.

I've tried setting up two different projects from scratch. I tried following the steps exactly as they were laid out. I was expecting the project to compile and run.

Comment: It's my own computer. I'm the admin on it. It sits on my desk in my house. There are no policy controls on it.

I really haven't done any more than what I've said I've done. I'm following a tutorial. It's step 2 that it fails on.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio <-- this is step 1.

I hit CTRL-F5 and I get an error.

I'm really not sure what other information I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my answer wasn't permission-related at all. It was Avast blocking the resulting RazorPagesMovie.exe file without allowing it to be created. Disabling it solved the problem.